# Health Check from filebeat to kibana with elasticsearch in the middle

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat, health-monitoring

I have to realize Health Check for a  system of logs based on the following architecture:

FileBeat ( Logs Files) - > AWS ElastiCache Redis - > Logstash ( 2 VMs) - > ElasticSearch (4 clusters ) - > Kibana

The purpose is to make sure of:

- The state of the Servers:

  1. Logstash ( OK / KO ) service?
  2. FileBeat ( OK / KO ) service?
  3. Redis Service  (OK / KO)?
  4. ElasticSearch ( OK / KO ) service?
  5. Kibana ( OK / KO ) service?
- Status Global (OK / KO) as,  a consequence of the arrival of the line of logs or not, from filebeat towards elasticsearch (at least) even kibana (ideally).

Please, can you give me yours suggestions for doing this health check ?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: yes,I update my question

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask   
Open ended and/or too broad questions are discouraged. Maybe you can provide things you've tried and are having difficulties with.  Examples and such..

Comment: Do you mean you'd like an integration test? I guess you'd just put a log entry in one one end and then see if it pops up on the other within the time dictated by your SLA (maybe with some safety margin). If you just want the individual servers monitored then use something like [Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit) in pretty much the standard way.